# Windows task fails because of .httr-oauth file

Tags: r, windows, google-bigquery

I've programmed a task using Windows task manager. It consists of accessing BigQuery data via `bigrquery` library. I've stored my credentials in a local file `httr-oauth`.

I'm using these libraries:

```
library(bigrquery)
library(assertthat)
library(httpuv)
```

The task has been working for a few weeks and suddenly I see this message in the log file (.Rout):

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Please point your browser to the following url: 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=....
```

It looks like token needs to be refreshed, but if I run the script manually everything is ok and my `httr-oauth` works fine.

Any idea about what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like your OAuth token is expired. When you've run it manually, have you been prompted to renew it? If so, has it overwritten the token you use for the scheduled task (maybe not, if you've done it from a different location)? If not, have you tried replacing it manually with the new token?

Comment: Is the file named `httr-oauth` without a prefix dot? It seems `.httr-oauth` (with a dot) is expected instead.

Comment: Yes, @Aurèle, it has a prefix dot and when I ran it manually it was overwritten by the new one. That's why I don't understand what's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you need to use a service account.

Find out how to configure the library driver to authenticate the connection with a Google **service account**. When you authenticate your connection this way, the driver handles authentication on behalf of the service account, so that an individual user account is not directly involved and no user input is required.

To authenticate your connection this way, you must provide a Google service account email address and the full path to a private key file for the service account. You can generate and download the private key file when you set up the service account.

More here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount